# script working only in spyder console

Tags: python, spyder

I everybody, I usually use spyder to write in python and I write these simple lines of code for plotting some graph but I can't understand why it doesn't work properly when I run it, but if I copy and paste the lines in the python console it works perfetly.
This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
z=np.arange(0,250,1)
f_z1=np.append([z[0:100]*0],[z[100:150]/2500 -(1/25) ])
f_z3=np.append(f_z2,[z[200:] *0])
plt.plot(z,f_z3)
```

I like to understand why I have this problem, thank for help.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: To follow on with what elyase said, it will be much easier for us to help you if you can edit your question to explain what you mean by "It doesn't work properly".  Do you get errors?  Does it just not show the plot?  Does it show the wrong plot?

Comment: if I run with F5 I obtain a constant line equal to zero, and if I run in spyder console I obtain a triangular function (the correct plot).

Comment: I found the issue; the / operator don't work element x element on an array, so instead divide for 25 I multiply for 0.04 and this works. Can someone explain me why the division operator have this strange behavior???

Comment: in the above code miss this line of code:f_z2=np.append(f_z1,[-((0.02)*(z[150:200]*(0.02)  -4)) ])

Comment: Try putting a dot after 2500, like 2500. and I think your problem will go away. Explanation here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division in Python < 3 works differently from what you may expect if you are used to for instance Matlab. So from a standard Python console you will get this (dividing integers results in an integer):

```
>>> 1/2
0
```

This has been changed in Python 3. To get the new behaviour put

```
from __future__ import division
```

above all the other imports in your script. Alternatively you could force floating point behaviour as follows:

```
>>> 1./2.
0.5
```

The reason why your code works in the Spyder console is because that already does the above import automatically.